# Dependency visualisation javascript library compatible with locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service, graph

I'm looking for a javascript library to visualise dependencies in a lightning component. I want to create something like this : [image]

So an element can have multiple parents and multiple children.

So far, I've tested :

- Sigma js
- Cytoscape js
- Joint js (with blackbone, lodash and jquery dependencies)

All 3 **are not working** with locker service enabled.

I've also tested d3 which works in locker service but is way too complicated for what I want to do (or don't know how to use it !)

Any suggestions here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only supported list of libraries that is updated can be found in the developer blogs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html).

The list includes:

> 1. React 0.14.8
> 2. ChartJS   2.1.4
> 3. D3    4.4.0
> 4. Leaflet   0.7.7 and 1.0.2
> 5. RxJS  Latest as of 12/5/16
> 6. Numeral.js    2.1.4
> 7. Underscore.js 1.8.3
> 8. FullCalendar  3.1.0
> 9. Gauge.js  1.2.1
> 10. jQuery   2.2.2 and 2.2.4
> 11. jQuery UI    1.11.4
> 12. DataTables   1.10.12
> 13. Select2  4.0.3

For any other libraries, you will have to test yourself unfortunately. (or wait for someone to post one)