# Add query-steps js library to a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am trying to add jquery-steps javascript library in my lightning 
component. But obviously it is not loaded.

This is the code I've used:

```
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/jquerystepcss" scripts='/resource/jquery,
/resource/jquerystepjs' afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
```

The jquery and the css files are loaded but not the query-steps one. 
Could you please advise how to debug this. Is it caused by the locker Service ?

Comment: [Debugging lightning components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185938/how-do-i-debug-my-lightning-component)

Comment: @glls is jQuery-steps supported by lightning ?

Comment: [Supported Locker service libraries](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184346/dependency-visualisation-javascript-library-compatible-with-locker-service/184371#184371)

Answer (score 2):

I consider jquerystepcss and jquerystepjs are the files in static resources. You should use the id(click on view file in static resource and get the id)
e.g https://*****c.ap1.visual.force.com/resource/**1500638472000**/dtcss

so finally your code should look like `<ltng:require styles="/resource/1500638472000/jquerystepcss" scripts='/resource/1500638472000/jquery,
/resource/1500638472000/jquerystepjs' afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />`

But these id's will get change when you move static resources and other stuff to production org so you should use below code

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', 
                        $Resource.jquery, 
                        $Resource.jquerystepjs)}"
              styles="{!$Resource.jquerystepcss}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.load}"/>
```

Get the details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm)